# How can I check if a library is available before compiling a C program

Tags: c, macros, compilation-time

Is there a way to include a library only if it is available to the compiler?

I thought about checking it with `#ifndef` (as shown below) but it just checks if a macro name is not defined and what I really need is to check if the compiler can reach to a C library in the compilation time.

```
#ifndef _MY_LIBRARY_H
    #include "my_library.h"
#endif
```

Is there a way to do this verification?

Comment: One popular way of doing this involves GNU autoconf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang and GCC have had a [`__has_include` macro](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#include-file-checking-macros) for a very long time, which you can use like this:

```
#if __has_include("my_library.h")
    #include "my_library.h"
#endif
```

It works with angle brackets too (in fact, it works with anything that you can pass to `#include`):

```
#if __has_include(<my_library.h>)
    #include <my_library.h>
#endif
```

`__has_include` has recently been anointed [standard C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include), meaning that C++ compilers that don't support it now will most likely have it in a not-too-distant feature. Since it's a preprocessor feature, C compilers that belong to the same suite as a C++ compiler have a high chance of getting the feature by osmosis as well.

Still, note that while `__has_include` will tell you if the header file is present, it won't save you from eventual linker errors in the case of a broken installation.

The old-fashioned way to do this is to have a pre-build script that tries to compile `#include "my_library.h"`, and output a configuration file with `#define HAS_LIBRARY_SOMETHING` to 0 or 1 depending on the result of that operation. This is the approach that programs like autoconf deploy.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the references. It worked well.