# Can I include different files based on platform?

Tags: c, c99

There is a header file that I include that only seems to exist on Linux machines, and not on MacOS machines. Although I can use a VM to compile and run the code, it would be nice to be able to do this in MacOS.

To be more specific, I am using `#include <endian.h>`, which compiles on Linux, and I would like to use [this compatibility header](https://gist.github.com/yinyin/2027912) for MacOS, which I would include with `#include "endian.h"`. My code compiles and executes as expected with the former include on Linux machines, and with the latter include on MacOS machines.

Is there a way to use platform-specific includes in the header (perhaps using some sort of `#if`-based syntax)? Or would this be bad practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macros for GCC/G++ to differentiate Linux and Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565979/macros-for-gcc-g-to-differentiate-linux-and-mac-osx)

Comment: You can have a `#include` line in between `#if` and `#endif` lines. If this doesn't answer your question can you be more specific?

Comment: There's information at the link you posted that shows how to do this.

Comment: This question is far more specific than the question linked to by @AlejandroVisiedo - I am asking about platform-specific includes, whereas the other question is asking about platform-specific macros.

Comment: @M.M Please read the question - I fully understand that `#if` and `#endif` can be used in this way; I'm just not sure which condition, if any, `if` would take.

Comment: @hitecherik Have you installed `Command Line Tool`?

Comment: @hitecherik the condition would be a platform-specific macro

Comment: @GRC I have `Command Line Tools` installed - it doesn't seem to make a difference in my case.

Comment: @AlejandroVisiedo - that is a good "related" link, but the answers (and comments) reference broken links, etc.. I'm not sure it would be worth closing this one relying on that one as the authoritative answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [endian.h not found on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813028/endian-h-not-found-on-mac-osx)

Comment: @hitecherik here is the exact problem you have:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813028/endian-h-not-found-on-mac-osx?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang and GCC support the `__has_include` preprocessor condition, which you can use instead of testing platform defines:

```
#if __has_include(<endian.h>)
#include <endian.h>
#else
#include "endian.h"
#endif
```

One thing to watch for, though, is that as `<endian.h>` is not a standard header, it could be possible that it's present on another platform with different definitions that don't really help you.

This is related to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457375/251153) that I wrote a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use platform-specific includes in the header (perhaps using some sort of #if-based syntax)?

yes:

```
#ifdef __MACH__
... // Mac headers
#elif __unix__
... // these will work for Linux/Unix/BSD even for Mac in most cases
#elif _WIN32
... // windows 32 bit
#elif _WIN64
... // windows 64 bit
#endif
```

> Or would this be bad practice?

I do not think so

The other solution if I remember correctly is installing `Command Line Tool` on Mac which will give you all headers for `gcc` in `Unix` like passion. Here is improvement to my answer, I knew I was forgetting something :( Oh well I only used Mac couple of times for development :S

- install the command line tools from the Xcode Preferences->Downloads window, or
- execute xcode-select --install from the Terminal command-line.

and here is the reference:

[endian.h not found on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813028/endian-h-not-found-on-mac-osx?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)